Next 14/15 Practical Use: Container Component Pattern

Let’s assume we have a search list view used in an admin UI.
In vanilla React, I structured it like this:

// SearchList.tsx .. mapped to route URL

const SearchList = () => {
    /* As a container component, it holds all sources of truth (state, logic, etc.) and only passes props down to its children */
    // ...

    return (
        <div>
            <SearchBox data={...} ... />  /* Presentation component that takes search params and event handlers as props */
            <Grid data={...} ... />  /* Presentation component that receives rowItems and event handlers as props */
        </div>
    )
}


However, when I moved this modeling approach to the Next app router, it seems like only truly static layout screens or sections that don’t refetch data can be purely server components. All the page.tsx files corresponding to the app router end up being client components.

In terms of efficiency and prop tracking, I still think the container component pattern is optimal. But now I’m questioning if I’m missing out on optimization benefits or causing JS bundles to grow too large. Sure, client components are still server-rendered to some extent, so it may not matter much. But on Reddit, I see a lot of debate: people arguing that using use client on every Next page defeats the purpose, while others use mostly client components and client-side data fetching.

For production use, how have you applied component patterns and state management when adopting Next? Do you pass down all state to lower components? For an interaction-heavy admin or business interface, that approach seems cumbersome. Any advice would be appreciated.



For the second section, try dynamic rendered server component described here.
Unless you need to use React hooks like useState, useEffect and etc.., you should first consider to employ Server Component.
